# Comparar se ja existe registro no BD MySql

Tags: mysql

Estou criando um sistema de reservas de salas, e possuo as seguintes colunas em minha tabela:

```
agenda_id
agenda_hora_inicial
agenda_hora_final
agenda_data_inicial
agenda_data_final
agenda_sala
```

Minha dúvida é como fazer com que o cliente só possar reservar uma sala vaga, e caso tente reservar uma sala já reservada retornar uma mensagem de erro.

Uma reserva no banco ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
o cliente "jose"
data_inicial: 22/05/2015 
data_final 22/05/2015
horario inicial 11:00
horario final 12:00
sala 01
```

Caso outro cliente tente reservar a sala após as 12:00h ele será liberado, mas das 11:00h até as 12:00h, não.

Comment: Explicite melhor a sua situação. Estás a usar alguma linguagem de programação para interagir com o Banco? Se sim, qual? Qual o ambiente? Detalhe melhor as suas ferramentas. E adicione mais tags. Sugiro um título mais condizente com a pergunta como: "Como verificar coincidência de datas no banco de dados?". Pode atrair mais pessoas.

Comment: Opa a linguagem que esta interagindo é php é um simples sistema de reserva por exemplo se ja existe uma reserva marcada para a data inicial a data final o horario incial o horario final e na mesma então não pode

Comment: Você repetiu três vezes **o que** quer fazer (contando a do comentário acima) não se repita tanto. Explique **uma** vez de forma inteligível. Adicione à pergunta o código que você já tem. O que você já tentou? Edite a sua pergunta com as informações necessárias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, vamos lá.

Primeiro, sua tabela tem sérios problemas de estruturação, você não guarda (pelo menos nessa tabela) em nenhum momento qual o cliente está fazendo a reserva, e também guarda a hora e minuto final/inicial em 4 colunas quando você pode facilmente utilizar apenas 2 colunas `DATETIME`, então, reestruturando sua tabela, ela ficaria assim:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| reserva_id      | smallint(6)  | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| cliente         | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| sala            | smallint(3)  | NO   |     | NULL              |
| reservado_em    | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| datahora_inicio | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| datahora_fim    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

<sub>* Note que o campo `cliente` é de texto, o ideal é você alterar esse campo pra `cliente_id` e definir uma chave estrangeira.</sub>

Código `CREATE` da tabela:

```html
CREATE TABLE `reservas` (
 `reserva_id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `cliente` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `sala` SMALLINT(3) NOT NULL,
 `reservado_em` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `datahora_inicio` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 `datahora_fim` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`reserva_id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6
;
```

Dessa forma, você pode cadastrar uma reserva utilizando:

```
insert into reservas(cliente, sala, datahora_inicio, datahora_fim) values('José', 001, '2015-05-25 11:00:00', '2015-05-25 11:59:59');
```

Então você pode verificar se no horário escolhido pelo cliente que está tentando fazer uma reserva já está reservado usando:

```
select * 
  from reservas 
 where (
            (datahora_inicio between '2015-05-25 11:00:00' and '2015-05-25 11:59:59') or
            (datahora_fim between '2015-05-25 11:00:00' and '2015-05-25 11:59:59')
         )
   and sala = 1;
```

[Veja o exemplo no SQLFiddle pra você testar as consultas.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c88f3a)

Comment: Brigadão Eduardo vou refaze-la e vou tentar agradeço o comentário

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM agenda WHERE agenda_sala = <id_da_sala> AND agenda_hora_inicial = <hora_inicial> AND agenda_hora_final = <hora_final> AND agenda_data_inicial = <data_inicial> AND agenda_data_final = <data_final>;
```

Se retornar 0, é pq não tem nenhum agendamento para aquela sala, na data e hora estipulada.

Comment: Se horário inicial for diferente do final a consulta não vai funcionar. Vai deixar que eu marque um registro das 7 às 9 e outro das 8 às 10 na mesma sala.